# VS Code C++ Automatic Syntax Error Highlighting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Currently VS Code will only highlight errors when the file is saved. This can get bothersome, as it isn't immediately apparent sometimes if you've mistyped something or are using something wrong etc.

Is there a way to make VS Code **automatically** show syntax/logical errors i.e red/green squiggles underneath code?

Comment: I have never seen VS behave that way.  Maybe something got turned off.

Comment: There are settings under tools/options/editor/<language>/advanced/intellisense that can affect the behavior.  I don't see anything that relates to functioning only when files are saved though.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with python but I have the same problem.

As shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_run-linting): "Linting runs automatically when you save a file."

Therefore, what I did to automatically lint, is enable Auto Save. With this configuration you can achieve linting almost in real time.

I guess that for C++ will work similar. Hope it helps.